# C++ How to reuse code of a (template) function, with different return type and slightly different behaviour?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++17, overloading

I have a task to do (C++). I have quite a big function that have lot of arguments and uses a lot of different function inside. It is quite complicated. Overall, it creates a container and add values to the container depends on what is going on inside. I have to check if returned container is empty or to get its size but without calling that function with size() or empty(). (Not to create container only to check if it is empty()). I was told to create similar (almost identical) function that detects if there was something added to container. For example, something like this but with very easy example:

```
std::vector<int> getData(int& a, int& b, int& c) {
    std::vector<int> result{};
    //complicated operations replaced by simple to show a problem
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(a - b > 0){
            result.emplace_back(c);
        }
        else if ( c == 1){
            return result;
        }
        else continue;
    }
    return result;
}
int getSize(int& a, int& b, int& c){
    int size = 0;
    //complicated operations replaced by simple to show a problem
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(a - b > 0){
            size++;
        }
        else if ( c == 1){
            return size;
        }
        else continue;
    }
    return size;
}
```

As you can see, functions are almost identical. The real function is much bigger and code duplication is high. I am wondering if there might be a solution to that. I was told that templates might be good solution but I have no idea how should I use it. Can someone help me?

Comment: I wouldn't use a template for this.  While the code structure is the same, the action performed, the return type, and parts of the body are different.  You would have just as much duplicate code making it a template and it would be less clear then it is now.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the common part in a separate function template that takes a functor as an argument and supply different functors, like lambdas, inside your `getData` and `getSize` functions.

Example:

```cpp
template <class Func>
void doStuff(int a, int b, int c, Func&& func) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (a - b > 0) {
            func();              // call func(), the supplied functor
        } else if (c == 1) {
            return;
        } else
            continue;
    }
    return;
}

std::vector<int> getData(int& a, int& b, int& c) {
    std::vector<int> result{};
    // capture `result` and `c` in the lambda:
    doStuff(a, b, c, [&result, c] { result.emplace_back(c); });
    return result;
}

int getSize(int& a, int& b, int& c) {
    int size = 0;
    // capture `size` in the lambda:
    doStuff(a, b, c, [&size] { ++size; });
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks perfect to me but ... The value i need to put to the container is not the real parameter. It is computed inside doStuff and then added to vector. Thats why i cant do it like this `[&result, c]{result.emplace_back(c);}` I heve tried do it like this: `[&result](int& c){result.emplace_back(c);}`. And when i have c computed in doStuff function call func like func(c). But right now i got error from getSize part because  lambda in getSize is called with no params. So i have func() vs func(c). Is there any way to fix that error ? I hope i explained that issue that u can understand

Comment: @mr__orangee If you update the question to include code that more closely resembles your real case, I will try to update my answer accordingly later.

Comment: @mr__orangee Any updates? I wouldn't mind expanding the answer if you can't make it work as-is.